# Dolphin emulator: Skyward Sword won't pass the "Connect motion plus" screen

Tags: emulation, zelda-skyward-sword, dolphin-emulator

I'm wondering how to enable motion plus. I'm using a control configuration from a youtube video, except adapted to my specific controller. I know Dolphin 5.0 has native motion plus support, but Skyward Sword doesn't seem to recognize it.
I've added my device to my control profile, like this:

```
[Profile]  
Device = DInput/0/Logitech RumblePad 2 USB
```

Comment: The latest stable version of Dolphin 5 was released 2 years ago, have you tried one of the more recent development builds? (for example, 5.0-10293 was released 11 hours ago) This has fixes some problems for me with physical controllers.

Comment: I had the most recent dev build, I believe. If it wasn't the most recent, then it was at most a month or two old.

Answer (score 3):

In the controller set-up screen, there is a checkbox labelled "Attach MotionPlus", if this is unchecked, your emulated controller will not be recognised as having MotionPlus capabilities.

[image: Dolphin Emulator Controller Screen]

Additionally, the [Dolphin Emulator Wiki](https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Skyward_Sword) says that versions of Dolphin prior to 5.0-10056, released 4 months and 3 weeks ago (May 3rd), were not capable of emulating the Wii MotionPlus. It is very possible that you were using a version which did not have this functionality, as in your own words if your version "wasn't the most recent, then it was at most a month or two old".